# Street coloring in a map

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

I have a database of my city with the name of a street and a number (from 1 to 5) representing  the average density of people.

I'd like to represent this on a map (doesn't matter if Google Maps or OSM or whatever), where I color the street from green to red depending that density.

The problem I don't know how to color a street, or even to draw a polyline on it.

Any ideas ?

TY !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Google maps APIv3 then creating/drawing the lines on the map isn't a tough task. The Gmaps3 documentation clearly explains using it-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines

The logic is pass your street coordinates(latlng's) to an array which can be used to draw a line on the map. Moreover you can change the colors of the polylines easily. For an idea of how to accomplish this, you can have a array with some set of colors like-

```
            var linecolors = [];
            linecolors[0] = '#3333FF';
            linecolors[1] = '#8A0808';
            linecolors[2] = '#B45F04';
            linecolors[3] = '#B18904';
```

and then depending on the density values appropriately take a color from the array while creating the polyline

**Update:** To find the street coordinates, directions service is what you may need.

[See directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests)

You can pass the address or location as origin and destination to `directionsService.route()` and use `travelMode DRIVING` . You get the street- [EXAMPLE](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

You can view and store the received coordinates using the chrome console- network tab(you will find downloaded js files with the coordiantes).

Comment: thank you cdeez ... the problem is not about polylines, as you said, they are easy ... the problem is to know the coordinates of a street (the whole street)

Comment: Well, the thing is ... how do I tell that API the start and the end of a street ? ... 1 Main Street, is the beginning (not always, but ok) ... but the end ? you can not set 9999 Main Street, it goes to the middle of the street.